# Convert UTC date from scientific notation to Java.util.Date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to convert the `created_utc` date from Reddit's json to a `Date` object, but I keep getting an "Unparceable" error.  An example of their dates is: `created_utc": 1.43701862E9,` which I'm told is a unix timestamp.

From my research this code should convert it:

```
String date = "1.43701862E9";
java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long)date*1000);
```

but obviously I'm getting an error on multiplying the date by 1000.

This is the code I normally use to convert string dates:

```
    String date = "1.43701862E9";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    format.parse(date);
```

Comment: There is not really any specific such thing as "Unix timestamp". [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is usually a count of whole seconds since the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone while ignoring [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). But not always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String date = "1.43701862E9";
    java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date(Double.valueOf(date).longValue()*1000);

    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Output:

```
Wed Jul 15 23:50:20 EDT 2015
```

---

Since you're using scientific notation you can't parse the `String` using the `Long` class: `Long.parseLong(String s)` (Nor can you simply cast a String, as you're trying).  Instead, I used the [`Double.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) method and preserve the `Long` using `.longValue()`

Answer (score 3):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31926504/642706) by Trobbins is correct but old-school. I lifted that Answer’s math, and used the new java.time classes.

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, you can use the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which supplants the troublesome old [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)/.Calendar classes. ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html))

```
String input = "1.43701862E9";
long milliSinceEpoch = Double.valueOf( input ).longValue() * 1_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliSinceEpoch ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId ) ;
```

Try to avoid java.util.Date/.Calendar, but if need be you can convert.

```
java.util.Date date = Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );  // Or… Date.from( instant );
java.util.Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt );
```

Comment: Coming from C# the Java Date class is something to be desired. How they can make it so convoluted is beyond me.

Comment: flawless answer!